# Confusion on finding if a limit exists or not.

Tags: calculus, limits

I have started the introduction of calculus in high school, and I am confused about this problem.

Define $f(x) = -x$ for $x<0$. Then find out if $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ exists or not. If it does, then state the value.

Here is my approach: The limit exists if $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} f(x)$ = $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x)$.

Then is it appropriate to state that $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} f(x) = 0$, because $0^{-}$ is still in the interval $x < 0$? It probably is. But, is it appropriate for $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) = 0$? I think not because $0^{+}$ is NOT in the interval. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: No.  $0^-$ is not  a number or a value and it is not in any interval.  To claim that a limit exists or doesn't exsist because $0^-$ or $0^+$ is in an interval simply makes no sense at all.  How does your text actually define limits.  Use that.

Comment: Some textbooks define limits in such a way that this limit exists. Some define limits in such a way that this limit does not exist. We would need to see the exact definition of a limit in your textbook to be sure what the correct answer is for you (you should follow that definition), although the fact that you are discussing $x\to0^-$ and $x\to0^+$ suggests an answer.

Comment: We dont use textbooks in my school. But here is my teacher defined limits to be: the limit of a function f(x) is the value that is approached by f(x) when x is approaching a certain value.

Comment: My teacher also taught me that a limit exists like if...  (see above question)

Comment: That is not enough of a definition to answer this question. Are you sure that's the entire "definition" and not just a way to help you see the purpose of the definition? (What you just said about the "definition" doesn't give you any reason to put $-$ or $+$ next to the number $x$ is approaching.)

Comment: Our teacher probably only writes out the simplified version of the definition for the sake of understanding. We are just starting out, actually.

Comment: It's not a simplified definition; that would require that it be an actual definition. It's actually just a hint. If I had to guess, I'd guess that your teacher will say this limit doesn't exist. If that is what your teacher says than we can infer something about how they really define limits. But I can only guess what your teacher will say, because it is perfectly possible to define the limit in such a way that this limit is well defined and the examples you have given are not sufficient to rule this out.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is my approach: The limit exists if $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} f(x)$ = $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x)$.

No. This is false. If $f$ is defined on an (possibly punctured) *interval* $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)\setminus \{a\}$, then yes, the limit $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$$ exists if and only if the two directional limits, $$\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x) \text {and }\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x)$$ exist.

However, since your funciton is not defined on such an interval, that particular fact cannot help you with calculating the limit.

---

Additinally, I would strongly warn you against sentences such as your last one, i.e. that "$0^+$ is not in the interval".

The interval is a set of numbers. Elements of the set are numbers. $0^+$ is not a number, it's just a collection of symbols used to denote a directional limit. So yeah, sure $0^+$ is not in the interval, but neither is $0^-$. The sentence is more or less nonsensical.

Comment: Sorry, I always I thought $0+$ is a very small positive value.. I also watch certain teachers at the internet that $0+$ is a very small positive value. So i guess i was misinformed. Thanks for your explanation

Comment: @Hayst No teacher ever says that $0^+$ is a small positive value. What they **do** say is that when taking $$\lim_{x\to0^+},$$ we can limit ourselves to looking only at small positive values of $x$.

Comment: I heard it from blackpenredpen.

Comment: @Hayst Then they are either wrong, are misleading you, or you misunderstood them. Without knowing the context, I cannot really say more. If you list the exact video, I could comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

The theorem you are trying to use
$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \text{ exists} \hspace{2mm}\text{iff} \lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a^-} f(x) $
only makes sense when a symmetric open neighbourhood can be open around $a$. The idea of neighbourhoods are a little more complicated than the intuitive definition of a limit and are sometimes omitted on high school courses, but basically the idea is that you can generate an open and bounded interval around the point $a$ that will be called neighbourhood.

Let me introduce the notion of the rigorous definition of limit without using extensive formal notation:
we say $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L  \text{ if you can take } x \in (-\delta + a,a+\delta) \text{ with } \delta >0 $ a small number, and you can insure that $ f(x) \in (-\epsilon+L,L+\epsilon) \text{ and } \epsilon$ is another small positive number. The idea is that given any small positive number $\epsilon$, you can give a positive $\delta$ that insures that all the $x$'s in the neighbourhood of length $2\delta$ around $a$, after being evaluated with $f$, $f(x)$ live in the neighbourhood of length $2\epsilon$ around L.

Lateral limits are in some way, a restriction of the original definition. We say $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = L $ if you can take $x \in (a,a+\delta)$ with $\delta>0$ a small number, and you can insure that $f(x) \in (-\epsilon+L,L+\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon$ another small positive number. As you can see, with the right lateral limit, we are considering the right half-part of the original neighbourhood of lenght $2\delta$ defined for the original limit definition. Analogously, $\lim_{x \to a^-} f(x) = L $ if you can take $x \in (-\delta+ a,a)$ with $\delta>0$ a small number, and you can insure that $f(x) \in (-\epsilon+L,L+\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon$ another small positive number. In this case, we are considering the left side of the interval. Now you can see why in some way we have an equivalence between the existence of the limit and the existence and coincidence of lateral limits.

As you can realize, both lateral limit definitions in some way are considering that when you take the intervals $(a,a+\delta)$ for the right limit and $(-\delta +a,a)$ for the left limit, you will find $x$'s in the domain that can be evaluated.

In your example, the problem is that you when trying to consider the right limit, and with that, you consider $(0,0+\delta)$, you will find no $x$ in your domain to evaluate your function since the domain is $\{x:x<0\}$, so you can't say anything about the right limit for $0$. (*True thing is you can say the right limit is anything you want using something called vacuous argument but don't bother your teacher in that way*). So I guess what you have to get clear is that there is no such thing as $0^+$ or $0^-$, this notation only represents the intervals from where you are taking the $x$'s that are close to $0$ and that when you have functions with domains as intervals like $(a,b)$ or $[a,b]$ or $[a,b)$ or $(a,b]$, you can only have well defined limits when considering $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x) $ and $\lim_{x \to b^-} f(x) = \lim_{x \to b} f(x) $

Answer (score 0):

In general, when the domain of a function covers all real numbers, your approach of comparing the left and right limits is valid. In this case however, the function $f(x)$ stops at $x=0$, so there is no need to calculate the limit approaching from the right side of $x=0$. All you need is the left limit, since that’s the only possible direction you can approach $x=0$ from.